# Building my first ASP application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I've just been tasked with building a web application using ASP (.net) and am looking for some advice on where to start.   In a nutshell the application needs to be able to.

- Handle user verification / authentication
- Handle sessions
- Do SOAP messaging

The application is intended to act as a front end for system functions that are accessible via web service calls.

I intend to do a lot of work on the client side using JavaScript and am thinking of using ASP solely as the framework for the 3 items I listed above.

Appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Visual Studio 2008 if you can. Its support for Ajax client libraries and javascript intellisense is very good. (Check out the [jQuery add in](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/10/28/rich-intellisense-for-jquery.aspx))

ASP.NET has built in Login controls (and the membership services mentioned by ChrisE), and also has Forms Authentication. Try to leverage these existing components and avoid using session to store user specific objects/data.

---session rant

*Its sometimes unavoidable, but you should avoid it whenever you can. It incurs a burden on the webserver for each user, and that leads to some very difficult scaling problems. The FormsAuthentication Ticket has a value property that you can store about 4K worth of user data in - try to use that instead.*

---End session rant

Try to use a MVC approach (not necessarily an [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)), but at least one that seperates your presentation / view layer from the data / model layer.

Create a default theme and use it. Most sites will need to have multiple themes later, and refactoring that will be a PIA.

If you need SOAP to interact with Non-.NET services then by all means use it. If you are only connecting to .NET services then look into WCF clients and services. They will give you more flexibility.

If you are doing the client work in javascript, then dont use the update panel. It adds lots of overhead.

Get FireFox + FireBug + YSlow, and IE8 (yeah its beta still). They will help you when dealing with the client end of debugging / styling.

Take a look at the [rules for website performance](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html), but take these with a grain of salt. They are intended for very large sites, and some of the items may not be applicable (CDN, DNS lookups, Redirects).

Answer (score 3):

WCF for Soap -- I would also suggest picking this up:

[alt ASP.NET 3.5 http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/518N8vYWf1L._SL500_AA240_.jpg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529562)

This book is in tutorial form -- and Jesse Liberty is a great teacher (as are his co-authors).

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET provides out of the box authentication/authorization through the SqlMembershipProvider and SqlRoleProvider classes, or you can use the ADMembershipProvider along with a custom RoleProvider to authenticate and authorize against an Active Directory setup.

Session handling is readily provided by ASP.NET as well, through an in-process server, an external StateServer service, or through a connection to SQL Server (and of course, you can provide a custom Session service if you need something different).

As Lou Franco mentioned, WCF provides the framework for the SOAP calls, and will blend in with your ASP.NET application quite handily.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ASP.NET Web Forms then for handling user authentication/verification I'd recommend ASP.NET Membership services http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx because it does some of the heavy lifting for you and also helps you from making any elementary security mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly related to your requirements, but I'd suggest you study the differences between Web Site and Web Application. The sooner the better. Everything will go smoother if you understand how the project is managed.

You can start here: http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx